# Cannot generate service reference after upgrading to Magento Enterprise v 1.11.1

Tags: magento

Last week our IT team upgraded from Magento Enterprise edition 1.11.0 to 1.11.1. Since then, I can no longer generate a service reference in a C# project in Visual Studio using the Magento API V2 WSDL URL. No errors are shown but the process fails and no code is generated.

To try and get more details I used SVCUTIL.EXE, a tool that is included with Visual Studio 2010, to generate the .NET classes that act against the service and in doing so I get numerous schema validation errors.

**Output snipet...**

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://[domain]/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.

Generating files...

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 44 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' has already been declared.

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 50 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Struct' has already been declared.

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 66 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:duration' has already been declared.

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 75 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:dateTime' has already been declared.

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 86 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:NOTATION' has already been declared.

Error: There was a validation error on a schema generated during export:
    Source:
    Line: 96 Column: 4
   Validation Error: The global element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:time' has already been declared.

**Question**

Has anyone else experienced this after upgrading to a new version of Magento? Is there anything in Visual Studio I can leverage to get more details about the error? As far as I can tell the problem originates with the WSDL provided by the Magento service.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Magento and the fix was to enable WS-I Compliance. To do so go to

System > Configuration > Magento Core API and set WS-I Compliance to Yes

This fixed my issue.